# To which part of the text is "most aggressively" is referring to?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this text:

> "Suffolk County on Long Island uses the state’s law, which takes weapons away from people who pose a danger to themselves or others, most aggressively."

is "most aggressively" referring to

> 1 - people who pose a danger to themselves or others

> 2 - the "danger" referred in the text, like a way of referring to danger as more intense

> 3 - the way the County takes weapons away from people?

Native English speakers may see it very clearly, but not someone learning English.

Comment: Which do you think the answer might be? Are there any answers you can rule out? Why? What *specifically* are you still confused about?

Answer (score 1):

It modifies "uses the state's law". You can remove the words in between the commas and then it should be clearer:

> Suffolk County on Long Island uses the state’s law most aggressively.

I don't have access to the full New York Times article (paywall), but I infer that this particular state law may be used differently by different counties, and this particular county uses it aggressively to take weapons away from people.

Comment: Probably best not to give a direct answer to what is obviously a homework question... wait for OP to explain their thought process and what work they have done to answer the problem, and what they are still confused about.

Comment: Not obviously homework to me.

Comment: @all not homework, I pratice English from abroad. All by myself. don't even have a teacher

Comment: I'd add that it's an awkward sentence - it might be better to move the aggressiveness nearer the verb e.g. "Suffolk County on Long Island very aggressively uses the state’s law, which takes weapons away from people who pose a danger to themselves or others." (I assume "most aggressively" means "very aggressively" rather than "more aggressively than any other county") Or "Suffolk County on Long Island uses the state’s law most aggressively, a law which takes weapons away from people who pose a danger to themselves or others."